# Delay a JSF AJAX listener for checkbox group

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a checkbox group (`h:selectManyCheckbox`) with an AJAX event to fire when boxes are checked or unchecked.  This is straightforward with `f:ajax`, e.g., `f:ajax execute="@form" event="click"`.

I'd like to enhance this to not re-execute after *every* click.  Instead, I'd like an idle delay such that if the user clicks three boxes in quick succession, there's only one round trip instead of three.

Is there a way to have a JSF AJAX listener (`f:ajax`) fire after a delay like this?

Comment: Why do you want to call an ajax function when you click on a checkbox? If you need to update or render some part of your page by doing this, use plain JavaScript, don't add extra calls to your server.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: re-applying business rules server-side before re-rendering.  Of course if I were just toggling visibility, I'd be doing straight jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not on JSF 2.2 yet, you could use JS `setTimeout()`/`clearTimeout()` to timeout the onclick and clear any previously set ones when clicked again.

E.g.

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox ... styleClass="delayClick">
    <f:selectItems ... />
    <f:ajax ... />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

with basically (also with a little help of jQuery)

```js
$(".delayClick input").each(function(index, input) {
    var onclick = input.onclick;
    input.onclick = null;

    $(input).on("click", function(event) {
        delay(function() { onclick.call(input, event); }, 1000);
    });
});

var delay = (function() {
    var timer = 0;

    return function(callback, timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, timeout);
    };
})();
```

If you're already on JSF 2.2, set the `delay` attribute of `<f:ajax>`.

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox ...>
    <f:selectItems ... />
    <f:ajax ... delay="1000" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Comment: Clever use of closure, I like it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code works also perfect for onblur events!