# JSF ajax event delay

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want to implement a live filter for a list with JSF 2 but when using `keyup` event so many requests are being sent to the server. The code looks like:

```
<h:inputText id="filter_input" value="#{bean.filterText}">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{bean.filter}" 
        render="@form:list" execute="@this" />
</h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`f:ajax` has added support for ajax event delay starting from JSF 2.2. Just include it as an attribute with its value in miliseconds:

```
<f:ajax event="keyup" delay="1000" listener="#{someBean.doSomething}"
    render="somefield" execute="@this" />
```

**See also:**

- [Primefaces keyup event delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401218/primefaces-keyup-event-delay)
- [Richfaces a4j event queuing](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_queue.html)
- [Delay a JSF AJAX listener for checkbox group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677179/delay-a-jsf-ajax-listener-for-checkbox-group)
- [JSF 2.1 Ajax autocomplete + server search only after user stops typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887863/jsf-2-1-ajax-autocomplete-server-search-only-after-user-stops-typing)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a previous version of JSF, PrimeFaces has been supporting a similar feature before JSF did:

```
<p:ajax event="keyup" delay="1000" listener="#{bean.filter}"
        update="somefield" process="@this" />
```

Note that PrimeFace does not use a `render` attribute nor does it use `execute`. Use `update` and `process` instead (although `process="@this"` is redundant beacuse it's already the default value for `p:ajax`)

here's the documentation :
https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/5.0/core/primefaces-p/ajax.html

And an other post that is related : [primefaces keyup event delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401218/primefaces-keyup-event-delay)

Comment: my bad, although, my answer is the PrimeFaces version instead of core JSF. I already faced the situation where I couldn't delay on f:ajax because we were using an older version of JSF. Primefaces have been supporting a delay for a longer time.